# How to use NSDictionaries values in BarGraph generation

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsdictionary, ios-charts

Need a little help please, I am reasonably new to the iOS developing and current stuck in a small problem.

I am trying to pass the values that I have got from JSON file into another method so I can generate the barGraph, but I am having problem to pass it as an String Array.

Here is the view controller class, I am trying to figure out a way to complete it, please also see the 2 classes that I have created, I can confirm the values are all there.

View Controller Class -

```
import UIKit
import Charts

class ViewController: UIViewController, ChartViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var barChartView: BarChartView!

    let model:JsonModel = JsonModel()
    var data:[Data] = [Data]()
    var censusYear:[String]! = []
    var currentData:Data = Data()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        barChartView.delegate = self 

        // Kick off the data gathering 
        self.data = self.model.getData()

        // Kick off the graph generation 

        setChart(<#T##[String]#>, values: <#T##[Double]#>)



    }


    func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

        barChartView.noDataTextDescription = " You need to provide data for the chart"

        var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

        for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
            let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
            dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        }

        let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "Population")
        let chartData = BarChartData(xVals: censusYear, dataSet: chartDataSet)
        barChartView.data = chartData
        barChartView.descriptionText = "This is a test"
        chartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.colorful()
        barChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0, easingOption: .EaseInBounce)



    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Data Class -

```
class Data: NSObject {

    var area:String = ""
    var censusYear:String = ""
    var sex:String = ""
    var population:Double = 0

}
```

JSON Data Model Class -

```
class JsonModel: NSObject {


    func getData() -> [Data] {

        // Get array of data objects
        var data:[Data] = [Data]()

        // Get JSON array of dictionaries
        let jsonObjects:[NSDictionary] = self.getLocalFile()

        // Loop through each dictionary and assign values to the data object parse JSON File
        var index:Int
        for index = 0; index < jsonObjects.count; index++ {

            // Current JSON Dict
            let jsonDictionary:NSDictionary = jsonObjects[index]

            // Create a Data object
            let d:Data = Data()

            // Assign value to each key value pair to the data object
            d.area = jsonDictionary["area"] as! String
            d.censusYear = jsonDictionary["census year"] as! String
            d.sex = jsonDictionary["sex"] as! String
            d.population = jsonDictionary["population"] as! Double

            // Add the data into data array
            data.append(d)

        }

        // Return list of data object


        return data


    }



    func getLocalFile() -> [NSDictionary] {

        // Get an NSURL object pointing to the JSON filed in the app bundle
        let appBundlePath:String? = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sample3", ofType: "json")

        // TODO: Use optional binding or guard to check if path exisits
        if let actualBundlePath = appBundlePath {

            // Path exists 
            let urlPath:NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: actualBundlePath)

            let jsonData:NSData? = NSData(contentsOfURL: urlPath)

            if let actualJsonData = jsonData {

                // NSData exists, use the NSJSONSerialization classes to parse the data and create the dictionaries 
                do {
                    let arrayOfDictionaries:[NSDictionary] = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(actualJsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! [NSDictionary]

                    return arrayOfDictionaries
                }
                catch {
                    // There was an error parsing the json file
                }

            }
            else {

                // NSData doesnt exist
            }
        }
        else {
            // Path to json file in the app bundle doesnt exist
        }


        // Return an empty array
        return [NSDictionary]()
    }
```

Comment: It looks like this would be easier if everything used `[Data]` rather than generating multiple arrays from different parts of the `Data` array.

Comment: What Phillip said is, you'd better use `[Data]` as the input of `setChart`, then get `dataPoint` and `value` from the model you defined. BTW, it's generally not a good idea to name your class as `Data`, but I can't find a good word for it just given the four fields you set. A country with sex?

Comment: Thanks guys, really appreciated your help. What do you think its the best way for me to use [Data] as the input ? sorry, just trying to get my head around it.  P.S. Its the graph to show the number split between Male/Female and etc.